# Gcc naked attribute leaves some trailing function prologue asm instructions

Tags: gcc, arm, system-calls, cortex-m, armv6

I've the following implementation for a svc exception handler on a cortex-m0:

```
int  __attribute__((naked))  
sv_call_handler(uint32_t n, uint32_t arg1, uint32_t arg2, uint32_t arg3,  
                uint32_t arg4, uint32_t arg5)
 {
      irq_off();
```

When I built it for cortex-m0 it looks like this:

```
   0x7a50 <sv_call_handler>        movs   r4, r0                                                                    
   0x7a52 <sv_call_handler+2>      str    r1, [r7, #12]                                                             
   0x7a54 <sv_call_handler+4>      str    r2, [r7, #8]                                                              
   0x7a56 <sv_call_handler+6>      str    r3, [r7, #4]                                                              
   0x7a58 <sv_call_handler+8>      bl     0x3194 <irq_off>
```

Resulting in a hard fault because of course, the value in R7 is 'undefined' and there is a high chance that it contains a value that isn't within the address range.

When I remove the naked attribute, the assembly makes much more sense:

```
   0x7a50 <sv_call_handler>        push   {r4, r5, r7, lr}                                                          
   0x7a52 <sv_call_handler+2>      sub    sp, #32                                                                   
   0x7a54 <sv_call_handler+4>      add    r7, sp, #8                                                                
   0x7a56 <sv_call_handler+6>      str    r0, [r7, #12]
```

I've used the naked attribute without issues before, so why does this happen now? Has it anything to do with the fact that the svc exception handler is a special case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use naked functions which take parameters. These parameters have to be handled by some prologue, which is highly likely not what you want.

Better off writing it in assembly (IMO).

Answer (score 6):

According to the gcc manual you can only use the `naked` function attribute for functions that only includes basic `asm` statements. Using extended `asm` statements or normal c-code in such function may appear to work but there are no guarantees what so ever.

In your code you you have a normal function call in your naked function. This is probably the root of your problem.